# Windows system32 access denied

Tags: asp.net

I got the following error in my .net application.

error : `Access to the path c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\ErrorLog.txt is denied.`

In internet some are telling about grant permission for folder. But after clearing temporary files in

```
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\Temporary ASP.NET
Files\
```

this issue got resolved.

Is this error due to large number of temporary files?? Please help me with a correct answer.

Comment: This problem can be resolved if you restart the iis server

Comment: Can i know why this error is caused. I need to give explanation to my manager.

Comment: May be the file was open in some other process

Comment: Is this caused due to temporary files?